# Modular form on $\Gamma_0(N)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $M(k,\Gamma_0(N))$ be a space of modular forms of weight $k$ on $\Gamma_0(N)$.
Each $f \in M(k,\Gamma_0(N))$ has a Fourier expansion of the form

$$f(\tau)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}a(n)\,q^n\quad\text{where}\quad q=\mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mathrm{i}\tau}$$

Now, let $g(\tau)$ be a function obtained from $f(\tau)$ by omitting all $a(n)$ such that $\gcd(n,N)\neq1$,
i.e.,

$$g(\tau)=\sum_{\substack{n\in \mathbb{N}\\(n,N)=1}}a(n)\,q^n.$$

Question: Is $g(\tau)$ a modular form? What level?

Many thanks